# Intercept array access using Bytebuddy

Tags: byte-buddy

I have been using Bytebuddy to monitor application behaviours, and I would like to check whether an array field of one of application classes is updated before executing a particular method. I have read Bytebuddy documentation and stack overflow questions and have found some useful documentation of how to intercept field accesses using `MemberSubstitution`.

However, because the field I'm interested in is an array, `onWrite` and `onRead` events in `MemberSubstitution` seem irrelevant.

Is it possible to track updates on an array field using Bytebuddy?

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately no. Arrays are read onto the stack. Then only afterwards elements are accessed by index. This can be preceded by arbitrary instructions and is not interceptable individually.